# Apache 403 Forbidden access denied

Tags: apache, configuration, installation, raspberry-pi4

**OS Debian 10 (Raspian)

Apache 2.4.38 on port 80

Lighttpd/1.4.53 on port 8080**

Although I have been tinkering with Linux for a few years, I am an intermediate user on my best day. I suspect that this is a very basic configuration issue. What am I missing?

**The Problem**
Apache will not allow files to load. It returns a 403/Forbidden error. Here is what I have done to date.

**The backstory**
Apache was installed some time ago. I tinkered with it when I set up WordPress but then dropped it because it was easier to work from a cloud stack. Two years ago I installed pihole. It was running on port 80 but I switched it 8080 a few days ago so I could install ownCloud which wants Apache and port 80. I have set up plenty of servers in the past (pihole, WordPress, Plex, Webmin, associated dependencies etc). ownCloud looked to be straightforward and totally doable so off I went. However, after completing the install I get a 403 Forbidden error. Note that I did not try to load the default "I'm Alive!" page prior starting so I don't know if it was accessible to begin with. I think probably not.

**Steps I have taken since**

1. Confirmed documentroot /var/www/html in apache.conf (below)
2. Confirmed status (systemctl status apache) and syntax (apache2ctl -t)
3. Examined directives in 000-default.conf (below)
4. Enabled debug and looked at log files for errors (below)
5. Checked permission on /var/www and /var/www/html to ensure www-data permissions.
6. Removed owncloud.
7. Uninstalled and reinstalled Apache.
8. Multiple reboots.

**../error.log**

```
[access_compat:error] [pid 9477:tid 2993677344] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/index.php, referer: http://192.168.1.10/
[access_compat:error] [pid 9477:tid 2983195680] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/favicon.ico, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
```

**/etc/apache/sites-avaialable/000-default.conf (stripping out the comments)**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /var/www/html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/apache/apache.conf (again, stripping out the comments for brevity)**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}

PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300

KeepAlive On

MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER} Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel debug

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied </Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted </Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Require all granted </Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
        Require all denied </FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

ServerName localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this. Not sure what the issue was but it was something very basic, either in the config files or with ownership/permissions. I solved it by installing another apache instance on a separate machine and then copying across the config and index files. I have no idea what of the root cause but... well it's done now.